# apche mod_fcgid, codeigniter and sendmail - timeout when trying to send mail

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, sendmail

I am having my own Debian server with LAMP installed, and a PHP web application based on CodeIgniter and configured to send mails using sendmail.
up to today everything worked great and the system easily sent mails. (last test was yesterday night)

But from this evening my server fail to send emails and I am getting the next apache error:

```
 mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds
```

I don't understand why this error suddenly appeared, I had looked at the `dpkg` log to see if any relevant package been added and nothing there.

```
`# cat /var/log/dpkg.log`
2014-11-03 07:59:18 startup archives unpack
2014-11-03 07:59:18 upgrade wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u1 1.13.4-3+deb7u2
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status half-configured wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status unpacked wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status half-installed wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status triggers-pending install-info:amd64 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status half-installed wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status half-installed wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status half-installed wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status unpacked wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u2
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status unpacked wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u2
2014-11-03 07:59:18 trigproc install-info:amd64 4.13a.dfsg.1-10 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status half-configured install-info:amd64 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
2014-11-03 07:59:18 status installed install-info:amd64 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
2014-11-03 07:59:19 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1 2.6.2-1
2014-11-03 07:59:19 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-11-03 07:59:19 status installed man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-11-03 07:59:19 startup packages configure
2014-11-03 07:59:19 configure wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u2 <none>
2014-11-03 07:59:19 status unpacked wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u2
2014-11-03 07:59:19 status unpacked wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u2
2014-11-03 07:59:19 status half-configured wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u2
2014-11-03 07:59:19 status installed wget:amd64 1.13.4-3+deb7u2
```

when I am using sendmail from command line it works great.

now, I might can fix it with adding an SMTP server, but I want to understand what had happen and why my Apache+PHP have problems with connecting to the sendmail.

**so this are my question:**
1. what is the cause for this behavior?
2. how can I track down this cause and prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of researching I had found the answer.
apparently,  I had accidentally limited my virtual server quota, when I had done so the apache server couldn't write anything to the file system, and any try to send mail failed.

I had just set the quota to unlimited and boom, problem solved.